# How to show floating icons inside gifted chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am trying to show a specific icon which will show above the chat list. I tried position:'absolute' in style but unable to succeed.Please tell me is it possible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write this line bottom of the gifted Chat View

```
*<Text style={{position: 'absolute',marginTop:200,right:0}}>Testing </Text>*
```